# "pass out from" vs "pass out of"

Tags: grammar

I got two sentences:

> 1) pass out **from** college.
>  2) pass out **of** college.

Could you tell me the difference in meaning when we use these two sentences?

Comment: Maybe this helps you https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/410345/does-the-phrase-pass-out-also-mean-to-graduate It seems that "pass out of college" is used mainly in Indian English but it's not common in BrEn nor AmEn.

Comment: I would be careful with using *pass out* to express *graduate*, because for AmEn, *pass out* is widely associated with *fainting*, so it might cause some confusion at first sight.

Answer (score 1):

[Cambridge Dictionary: pass out](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pass-out)

> to pass out = to become unconscious for a short time, for example when ill, badly hurt, or drunk: `I was hit on the head and passed out.`

This is the most used meaning. In many cases, people may not even know the other meaning (which is related to military schools anyway).

So, if you want to avoid confusion, do not associate `to pass out` with graduating - unless you fainted during the ceremony :)

Answer (score 0):

In reading the two sentences, the following would be the common interpretations:

> pass out **from** college
>
> parsed  (pass out) from college

This means that you lose consciousness because of college.

Because of the preposition *from*, it is saying that college is the result of the phrasal verb *pass out*.

---

> pass out **of** college
>
> parsed  pass (out of) college

This means that you have passed through and out of college. So, you've graduated.

The use of the preposition *of* results in it being not the phrasal verb *pass out* that means to lose consciousness but a simple construction of the verb *pass* followed by the prepositional phrase *out of*.

---

Having said that, using *pass out* at all might give the wrong impression, even if *of* is used as the preposition rather than *from*. But I would certainly avoid using *pass out from* in every case.